# How do groups of IDs in rows of one pandas dataframe and use them to extract records from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. One contains the contact information for individuals and households. The other contains an ID field for a Household, followed by the individuals in that household. I would like to select all records from the first dataframe and insert a column with their associated Household ID.

Minimum reproducible:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Constituent Id':['111111','222222','333333','444444','555555','666666','777777'],
               'Type':['Individual','Household','Individual','Household',
                       'Individual','Individual','Individual'],
               'Name':['Panda Smith','Panda and Python','Python Jones','Postgres Family',
                       'Paul Postgres','Mary Postgres','Sqlite Postgres']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Account_ID':['ABCDEF','GHIJKL'],
                    'Household_0':['222222','444444'],
                    'Individual_0':['111111','555555'],
                    'Individual_1':['333333','666666'],
                    'Individual_2':['','777777']})
```

Resulting in:

```
 >>> df1
      Constituent Id        Type              Name
    0         111111  Individual       Panda Smith
    1         222222   Household  Panda and Python
    2         333333  Individual      Python Jones
    3         444444   Household   Postgres Family
    4         555555  Individual     Paul Postgres
    5         666666  Individual     Mary Postgres
    6         777777  Individual   Sqlite Postgres
>>> df2
      Account_ID Household_0 Individual_0 Individual_1 Individual_2
    0     ABCDEF      222222       111111       333333             
    1     GHIJKL      444444       555555       666666       777777
```

What I want to do is append a column to `df1` with the `Account_ID` that applies to each of the individuals in the account. Households aren't necessary, but it's fine if I include those.

Because the number of individuals varies in each Household, I couldn't think of a great way to do this without iterating over each row. That seems very un-pandas and I'm sure there's a better way, perhaps by stacking or something.

In my example, the output would look like:

```
  Constituent Id        Type              Name   Account_ID  
0         111111  Individual       Panda Smith      ABCDEF
1         222222   Household  Panda and Python      ABCDEF
2         333333  Individual      Python Jones      ABCDEF
3         444444   Household   Postgres Family      GHIJKL
4         555555  Individual     Paul Postgres      GHIJKL
5         666666  Individual     Mary Postgres      GHIJKL
6         777777  Individual   Sqlite Postgres      GHIJKL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC need `melt` then `merge`

If . `Type` isn't required you can ommit it from the 2nd line and merge clause.

```
s = pd.melt(df2,id_vars='Account_ID',var_name='Type',value_name='Constituent Id')
s['Type'] = s['Type'].str.split('_',expand=True)[0]
```

---

```
print(s.head(5))
  Account_ID        Type Constituent Id
0     ABCDEF   Household         222222
1     GHIJKL   Household         444444
2     ABCDEF  Individual         111111
3     GHIJKL  Individual         555555
4     ABCDEF  Individual         333333
```

---

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1,
         s,
         on=['Type','Constituent Id'],
         how='left'
        )

print(df3)

  Constituent Id        Type              Name Account_ID
0         111111  Individual       Panda Smith     ABCDEF
1         222222   Household  Panda and Python     ABCDEF
2         333333  Individual      Python Jones     ABCDEF
3         444444   Household   Postgres Family     GHIJKL
4         555555  Individual     Paul Postgres     GHIJKL
5         666666  Individual     Mary Postgres     GHIJKL
6         777777  Individual   Sqlite Postgres     GHIJKL
```